# Find file, convert it and leave in orginal directory in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a simple script to convert `.docx` to `.pdf`:

```
for d in $(find /home/kfalasz/Pulpit/konwersjapdf -maxdepth 3 -name "*.docx")
do
  soffice --headless --convert-to pdf $d
  rm $d
  echo $d
done
```

it works good but all converted files are in `/home/kfalasz/Pulpit/konwersjapdf` and I would like to leave them in orginal directory for example file `/home/kfalasz/Pulpit/konwersjapdf/a/plot.docx` convert to `.pdf` and leave in `/home/kfalasz/Pulpit/konwersjapdf/a/plot.pdf` and actually it leaves file in `/home/kfalasz/Pulpit/konwersjapdf/plot.pdf`.

How to keep the orginal file tree?

Comment: BTW, `for d in $(find ...)` falls afoul of [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using GNU Tools

GNU `find` itself can do what you want:

```
find /home/kfalasz/Pulpit/konwersjapdf -maxdepth 3 -name "*.docx" \
  -execdir soffice --headless --convert-to pdf '{}' ';' \
  -delete
```

`-execdir` causes each command to be run directly in the location where the file was found.

Because `-exec` and `-execdir` only pass on `true` when the command in question succeeds, this will only delete files which `soffice` was able to convert.

---

#### On All POSIX Platforms

As an alternative that works on *all* versions of `find`, not only GNU releases, consider:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -name "*.docx" -type f -exec sh -c '
  for p do
    (cd -- "${p%/*}" || exit; exec soffice --headless --convert-to pdf "${p##*/}") \
      && rm -f -- "$p"
  done' _ {} +
```

Here, the subshell created by the `(` scopes the effect of `cd`; the `exec` then consumes that subshell, ending the scope at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can include `--outdir` with your command:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "${d%/*}" $d
```

Where `${d%/*}` trims the last bit of the file name off and leaves the basename of the directory.

You could alternatively use `pushd` and `popd` to change the cwd there, but personally I'd prefer the flag option.

Comment: The last `$d` should also be quoted.

Comment: Got an error `Error: source file could not be loaded` so used @CharlesDuffy answer. Prolly it's connected with BashPitfalls #1 added by Charles in comment. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `soffice` installed, but it sounds from OP's answer, appropriate flag is the way to go here. Here is a `pushd` `popd` version using `find`

```
$ find . -maxdepth 3 -name "*.docx" | \
 xargs -I {} bash -c 'p="{}";
                      pushd $(dirname "$p") >/dev/null; 
                      bp=$(basename $p); 
                      soffice --headless --convert-to pdf "$bp"; 
                      popd>/dev/null;'
```

Comment: **As currently written, this has serious security bugs.** If you have a file created with `touch $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\'.pdf'`, guess what happens when `p={}` gets substituted with that name?

Comment: It *can* be made safe, however. Take out the use of `xargs`, and make it `find ... -exec bash -c 'for p; do ...; done' _ {} +`

Comment: See the warning at the top of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-. BTW, another approach is to avoid `pushd` and `popd` and just have a subshell change into each directory -- we thus pop out to the parent intrinsically when it exits; and if you make it `exec soffice`, you're using the subshell's PID to run `soffice`, so you aren't paying any increased efficiency penalty.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i'm having difficulties grasping your fixed command, can you point me to some resources regarding that? what's the meaning of the underscore?

Comment: The underscore is a placeholder for `$0`, whereas arguments after it become `$1`, `$2`, etc in the invoked command (thus also entries in `"$@"`, which is what a `for` loop iterates over by default). See [the *Actions In Bulk* section of UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-)

Comment: (Err, my very first comment should have had a `.docx` extension rather than a `.pdf`, of course).

Comment: (btw, the point of the two separate command substitutions in the filename `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.docx` is to demonstrate that the attack still works in all three cases between `p="{}"`, `p='{}'` and `p={}`; in the first, both substitutions execute, in the second, only the second one executes, and in the third, only the first one executes).

Comment: Alternately, you could make this safe by changing `p="{}"` to `p=$0`, and then changing the last line to `popd >/dev/null;' '{}'` -- the critical difference being that that way you pass your data out-of-band from your code, so malicious data can't try to mount an injection attack.

Comment: ...btw, what's the point of `popd` at all here? `xargs -I` implies `-n 1`, so you're only having `xargs` start one copy of bash per file, so having that copy change back to a prior directory doesn't matter -- it's going to exit (and let a new copy be started in that original/prior directory) regardless.